# Nginx deny access to all PHP files but one from certain IPs

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I am trying to deny access to all of our PHP scripts except one for all outside world except one IP.

```
    location / {
            deny all;
            allow <one-ip-address>;

            error_page 403 goodpage.php;

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            deny all;
            allow <one-ip-address>;

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /goodpage.php {
            allow all;

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

However, whatever I do, I always end up restricting all *.php or none.
Setup is Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx 1.10.0, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the order of the allow and the deny. The "deny" in this case overwrites that allow rule you have written

Comment: I have done that, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the evaluation order for `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The simple solution would be to change the prefix location to an exact match location. For example:

```
location = /goodpage.php {
    ...
}
```

As Orphans points out, the `deny all;` statement needs to be after any more specific `allow` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny) for details.